# Multi select dropdown reset isn't working in dropkick.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-dropkick

I have created two multi select drop down using [dropkick js](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick), like nested drop down

Second dropdown options will populate based on first dropdown.
I have placed my populating code whenever outer dropdown change event occurs.

When I tried to reset (to uncheck the selected items and reload the options) the both dropdown at the same time like

```
$('#outerSelect').dropkick('reset'); //working
$('#innerSelect').dropkick('reset'); //not working
```

My inner dropdown gets reset, but my outer dropdown not resetting.

But when commented out inner dropdown html codes and tried to reset the outer dropdown, it's working fine.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got answer for my question from the following link

https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick/issues/235

work around for the issue happened plug-in used.

Answer (score 0):

*This is just a suggestion*

You should try and implement select2. It's much better and powerful than dropkick. You can get it here [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). Check it out and you'll thank me.